# How to control shared library version issue on Linux?

Tags: shared-libraries

For example, I create a shared library named **libXXX.so.0.0.0** with the soname as **libXXX.so.0**. So, do I need to create a symlink named **libXXX.so.0** and let it points to the real shared library? Or do I just need to create a symlink named **libXXX.so**?

Besides, what if I update the library to **libXXX.so.0.0.1**?

1. If I install the shared library on the system library path, such
   `/lib` or `/usr/lib`, how to update the symlink? Using
   ***ldconfig***?
2. If I install the shared library on current local folder, how to
   update the symlink?

BTW, how control the version issue in Makefile? I mean do I need to add some command such as ***ln -s*** or ***ldconfig***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a symlink named `libXXX.so.0` pointing to `libXXX.so.0.0.0`.

If you want people to be able to construct programs that are linked against this library then also create a symlink named `libXXX.so` pointing to `libXXX.so.0`.

The libXXX.so.0 symlink will be used by the program loader, because that's the soname that the program will be looking for.

The `libXXX.so` symlink will be used by the linker when it is building a program, because by historical convention that's how the linker works.

> Besides, what if I update the library to libXXX.so.0.0.1?

Then you remake the `libXXX.so.0` symlink so that it points to `libXXX.so.0.0.1`.  Nothing else needs to change.  Since the `libXXX.so` symlink points to `libXXX.so.0` it will automatically also point to the new library.

> how to update the symlink?

If you're installing the new library by using some packaging system (RPM, ...) then use whatever feature the packaging system provides for managing symlinks.  If you're just using a script or a Makefile stanza then simply `rm -f` the old symlink and `ln -s` the new one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your nice reply! BTW, how and when **ldconfig** command works?

Comment: **ldconfig** manages a cache of soname-to-pathname translations. (Run **ldconfig -p** to see those items.)  It doesn't know or care about the micro-versioned files that those pathnames really point to.  This cache can reduce the time it takes to find libraries at program startup, because the loader no longer needs to traverse the list of default library directories looking for a file whose name matches the soname that the program requires.

Comment: I do not completely understand @ottomeister comment. ldconfig makes cache to be faster for a program to link on start up. This is OK. But, does ldconfig also looks for new version of library or not? E.g. Should I handle symbolic link manually when install new library version, or will ldconfig do it automatically for me? I also believe that I found answer in manual: `ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found`, but can you confirm that I am not looking something wrong?